# Delta Delivering Failed - Deltalog for customer_entity, is not installed in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

How can the "Deltalog" be "installed"?

Migrating  magento 1.9.2.4 >> 2.1.0

Migration Tool Version 2.1.0

[image]

Comment: i get this problem too. Do you resolve it?

Comment: I got the same issue. Here I use live DB dumb to migrate data and after migration, i have copied all m2_db to latest dumb of live and run delta migration step with latest live db. Then the same error occurred. Do anyone fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to run `bin/magento migrate:delta` step you first need to run the `bin/magento migrate:data` step because it is in this step where the [Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool) creates triggers in the source database.

Those triggers will be used to pull ***only the changes made in Magento 1 since the last time you migrated data.***

[image: Data Migration Tool source table prefix]

For more information have a look to the [Official Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/bk-migration-guide.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi @diazwatson, I have migrated data before by taking dump of m1 db to local and migrated successfully, now for new changes again taken dump and started delta migration, I am getting above error this time

Comment: @jafarpinjar delta mode will only work on the same source database that you used to run migration for the reasons explained in this answer i.e., triggers are created on the source db. if you attempt to run delta on a source db that has not been used as a source for data:migrate, you will get this error.

Comment: Hi @diazqatson can you help me on this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289423/magento-2-delta-migration-issue-with-bob-file

Comment: Is there any way to continue with delta in this kind of situation? Can we move those tables from test installation into production so that we can complete delta? They seem to empty in our case so I'm not sure what is the functionality of those tables.

Comment: i have migrated data few minutes ago, and run delta migration got this issue, Do i need to run the data migration again then delta migration.

Comment: delta step will migrate new incremental data from m1 to m2, if there is no new data nothing will be migrate.