# Magento 2: How can we migration only customers and orders data using Data Migration tool?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool

In my current Magento 2 instance I have added products and categories manually as well as all the settings.

Is it possible to migrate only orders and customers data from my old site using Data Migration tool?

Comment: Migrate Sales and Customers data done or not?

Comment: No it wasn’t worked earlier. So I have to do some manual work

Comment: @HitarthPattani, yes it's possible, but if you have already imported products and categories, migration tool will work with only fresh database, hope you may get errors

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but you will have to modify a bit the config files to get what you need.

Here is an example of the Data Migration Tool `config.xml` used to migrate **only customers and newsletters subscribers**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Data Integrity Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
    </step>
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Newsletter Subscribers Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Newsletter\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Newsletter\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Newsletter\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<steps mode="delta">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<source>
    <database host="172.x.x.x" name="source-db-name" user="dbuser" password="dbpassword"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="172.x.x.x" name="source-db-name" user="dbuser" password="dbpassword"/>
</destination>
<options>
    <map_file>etc/ce-to-ee/1.7.0.0/map.xml</map_file>
    <customer_map_file>etc/ce-to-ee/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
    <customer_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ee/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
    <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ee/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
    <delta_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ee/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
    <map_document_groups>etc/ce-to-ee/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
    <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
    <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
    <source_prefix />
    <dest_prefix />
    <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
    <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
    <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
    <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
    <edition_migrate>ce-to-ee</edition_migrate>
    <edition_number>1.7.0.0</edition_number>
    <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
    <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
    <crypt_key>xxxxxxxxpatataxxxxxxxxxx</crypt_key>
</options>
```

In this example you can see how all unnecessary steps have been removed to leave only `Customer Attributes Step` which is in charge of customer migration.

`Newsletter Subscribers Step` is a custom step created to migrate specific data.

You can use this example to modify your `config.xml` file and migrate only customers and sales data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello @diazwatson, I have tried to migrate data using delta migration, but seems like the we have to use the same database that we have used for first data migration. Am I Correct?  I need to migrate customers and sales data only from scratch. Can we do that using delta migration?

Comment: Hi, 
That is correct!, 

You have to use the same database you used for first data migration because it is in `data` step where the tool creates what it needs for `delta` step to work.

Comment: @hitarth-pattani I just remembered a similar question I answered, related to `delta` step. It may help you achieve what you want to do.
 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132744/delta-delivering-failed-deltalog-for-customer-entity-is-not-installed-in-mage/184193#184193

Comment: Hello @diazwatson, Yes I do know that this delta migration requires m2_cl_* tables which was created at the first time of data migration. but my requirement is to migrate only customer and sales from M1. Do you have any reference for this? Or if you can guide me on that which helps a lot.

Comment: Have you read my answer?, I think I already gave you a good example of what you need to do to achieve what you want :)

Comment: @HitarthPattani skip custom tables in config file https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213263/data-migration-from-magento-1-9-1-to-2-1-9   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92551/sales-order-grid-is-empty-after-data-migration

Comment: How to migrate custom m1 tables to m2?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Follow 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-migrate-data.html

**Difficulty:** You only need to migrate customer and sales data only.

**Solution:**

**Steps Overview**

> 1. install data migration tool.
> 2. Map tables for sales and customers only in `map.xml` file and skip all other unnecessary steps in `config.xml` file.
> 3. Solve errors step by step if occurred.

**1.Install**
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-tool-install.html

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.x( your installed version)
```

**2.config** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

> config.xml file located in
>   `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1(your_version)`.
>   if not find rename `config.xml.dist` to `config.xml`
>   *Comment all unnessary*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
     <!--   <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>  -->
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
      <!--  <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step> --> 
     <!--   <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>  -->
      <!--  <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>  -->
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
      <!--  <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>  -->
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
     <!--  <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step> -->
      <!--  <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step> -->
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
```

**map.xml file** located in vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1(your_version). if not find rename from `map.xml.dist` to `map.xml`

> *comment those which need to migrate* and `<move>` used to move, `<field_rules>`  used for table fields, `<document_rules>` used for
>   tables and `<ignore>` for ignore fields

```
<map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../map.xsd">
    <source>
        <document_rules>

            <ignore>
              <document>googleshopping_attributes</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>googleshopping_items</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>googleshopping_types</document>
            </ignore>
        <!--    <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_invoice_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_order_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_shipment_grid</document>
            </ignore> 
            <ignore>
                <document>customer_entity</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>customer_entity_datetime</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>customer_entity_decimal</document>
            </ignore> -->

        </document_rules>
        <field_rules>
             <move>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.grand_total</field>
            <to>sales_creditmemo_grid.order_base_grand_total</to>
            </move>
         <!-- source table custom  grid field-->
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_invoice_grid.base_grand_total</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_to_order_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_to_order_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_to_base_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_to_global_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.creditmemo_status</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.invoice_id</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.order_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>

        </field_rules>
    </destination>
</map>
```

**3. RUN **  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/migration/migration-migrate-data.html

```
bin/magento migrate:data {<path to config.xml>}
```

> Possible errors : Source documents are not mapped:(customer_)tables. check `config.xml` and `map.xml` file again if custom migration then use `setting.xml` also
>
> **Note:** try , try and try until you will complete migration. Just focus
>   on every errors and steps.

Comment: the above code is working?

Comment: @senthil Yes it was working..  Any doubts ??

Comment: So it is not working?