# Data Migration From Magento 1.9.1 to 2.1.9

Tags: magento-2.1, data-migration

I am using magento data migration tool. I followed http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate-data.html

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '1-17' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'

**[solved]**   sales_flat_creditmemo_grid,sales_flat_invoice_grid,sales_flat_order_grid,sales_flat_shipment_grid
   on map.xml for don't ignore why it show they are not mapped.

I got error after followed step by (Rakesh Jesadiya ). [Sales Order Grid is empty after data migration process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92551/sales-order-grid-is-empty-after-data-migration)

**[updated][solved]**
Destination fields are not mapped.( I mistaken put inside`<document_rules>` it should be `<field_rules>`)

```
sales_creditmemo_grid. Fields: order_status,billing_address,shipping_address,customer_name,customer_email,customer_group_id,payment_method,shipping_information,subtotal,shipping_and_handling,adjustment_positive,adjustment_negative
```

> sales_invoice_grid. Fields:
>   store_name,customer_name,customer_email,customer_group_id,payment_method,billing_address,shipping_address,shipping_information,subtotal,shipping_and_handling

even these field include in **map.xml** under `<destination>`

```
<ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.order_status</field>
    </ignore>
```

[image]

***here my config.xml ***:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
     <!--   <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>  -->
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
     <!--   <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>  -->
      <!--  <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>  -->
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
      <!--  <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>  -->
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
      <!--  <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step> -->
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
```

**My map.xml file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../map.xsd">
    <source>
        <document_rules>

            <ignore>
              <document>googleshopping_attributes</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>googleshopping_items</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>googleshopping_types</document>
            </ignore>
        <!--    <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_invoice_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_order_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_shipment_grid</document>
            </ignore>  -->
            <ignore>
                <document>customer_entity</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>customer_entity_datetime</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>customer_entity_decimal</document>
            </ignore>

        </document_rules>
        <field_rules>
             <move>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.grand_total</field>
            <to>sales_creditmemo_grid.order_base_grand_total</to>
            </move>
         <!-- source table custom  grid field-->
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_invoice_grid.base_grand_total</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_to_order_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_to_order_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_to_base_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_to_global_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.creditmemo_status</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.invoice_id</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.order_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>

        </field_rules>
    </destination>
</map>
```

But orders,customers data are not showing in admin panel.. 
products also showing like this. 
[image]
[image]

-