# Homepage became white screen after successful data Migration with no error log

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, data-migration, data-migration-tool

**Problem:** White screen after data Migration.

**Precondition:**

- I Migrate from Magento 1.9.1 to Magento 2.1.9 with lots of custom
  extensions and customization. So I skip custom code & database tables migration .
- I create custom theme and used lots of Magento 2 extension to
  a fulfilled requirement like banners, testimonials, blogs.. etc

I successfully did data migration from Magento1.9.1 to 2.1.9. [Links how I did Migration using Data-migration-tools](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213263/data-migration-from-magento-1-9-1-to-2-1-9) (customers,reviews,orders,catalog,settings)
I tried both with settings and without settings. After successful migration, my home page became white with No error log

What I tried many times upgrade, compile code clear static content.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I enable developer mode and set profiler also

```
bin/magento setup:mode:set developer

SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER "html"
```

when I see source code nothing wrong, means complete homepage code with inspect element/console.

How should I debug Now? any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.
Try adding these lines to your index.php

[image]

Comment: It is bootstrap.php. Not index.php.

Comment: Sorry about the screenshot. It's index.php not bootstrap.php