# Delta migration error in magento 2

Tags: magento2, data-migration, data-migration-tool, delta-migration

I am working on magento migration using default magento migration tool.

Followed all the steps and migrated data successfully.

**I followed the below procedure to migrate data:**

1. Took the dump of M1 Production site database to local
2. Installed M2 new instance.

Configured source and destination in config.xml file of migration tool

Data migration happen successfully.

Now i need to migrate the changes, Did the following changes.

1. Took the dump of M1 Production database into local(**After 1 week of data migration**)

Configured source and destination in config.xml file of migration tool

Then run the below command to migrate the changes.

```
   php -d memory_limit=10G bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.4/config.xml
```

I am facing below error,

```
  Delta Delivering Failed - Deltalog for customer_entity, is not installed in Magento 2
```

Which means Data Migration Tool creates triggers in the source database. they are used in delta migration. source ->[Delta Delivering Failed - Deltalog for customer_entity, is not installed in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132744/delta-delivering-failed-deltalog-for-customer-entity-is-not-installed-in-mage/184193#184193)

But this time the database is different where i took the latest dump to local and trying delta migration, which is making problem for me.

How can i migrate changes once the data transfer is done successfully.

Can anyone help me on this please. Thanks

Comment: Is your Delta migration worked perfectly?

Comment: @EjilarasanJ, No not completely

Comment: `code`bin/magento migrate:data -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/config.xml`code`

Products and Customer are dumped perfectly. For, me the order's media gallery throws duplicate. Trying to fix it and let you know the whole flow.

Answer (score 0):

Do the below steps to make the delta migration success.

1. Take a dump of the full production DB of 1.9 eg. Table_pro.
2. Already having the Magneto 2 DB with certain data.
3. If Magneto opensource, under the folder of M2 - /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/<-- YOUR MAGENTO VERSION -->/config.xml ignore config.xml.dist

`<source>
    <database host="IP" name="M1.9DB_NAME" user="magento" password="magento"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="IP" name="M2_EXIST_DB_NAME" user="magento" password="magento" />
</destination>`

**Need to ignore any tables or remove any ignored tables, map them on *map.xml* like below.**

[image]

Finally, run the below command from Magento root SSH. For mine, the Magento version is 1.9.0.1.

> bin/magento migrate:data -a
>   vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/config.xml

If any issues raised, we can easily sort out it and make the Magento 2 DB up to date.

The above steps working fine for me.