# Magento 2 migration issue with payment transaction id

Tags: magento2, sales, data-migration, delta-migration

We are able to migrate data successfully with sales payment transaction table.

**map.xml**

```
<transform>
                <field>sales_payment_transaction.additional_information</field>
                <handler class="\Migration\Handler\SerializeToJson" />
</transform>
```

Which is not transforming/working at the time of migration.

For Example 
    Expected Result:

```
Instance          :      M1 
Table Name      :     sales_payment_transaction
Column Name  :     additional_information
Serialized Data :    A:1:{s:19:"real_transaction_id";s:22:"5574217307766210204089";}


Instance          :      M2 
Table Name      :     sales_payment_transaction
Column Name  :     additional_information
Json Data        :    {"real_transaction_id":"5574217307766210204089"}
```

Actual Result:

```
 Instance:      M1 
Table Name      :     sales_payment_transaction
Column Name  :     additional_information
Serialized Data :    A:1:{s:19:"real_transaction_id";s:22:"5574217307766210204089";}


Instance          :      M2 
Table Name      :     sales_payment_transaction
Column Name  :     additional_information
Json Data        :     A:1:{s:19:"real_transaction_id";s:22:"5574217307766210204089";}
```

The above example not working at the time of DELTA mode. Please suggest on this

Exception log

```
report.CRITICAL: a:1:{s:19:"real_transaction_id";s:22:"5682952820116120004012";}Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): a:1:{s:19:\"real_transaction_id\";s:22:\"5682952820116120004012\";}Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error at /var/www/html/tupperware/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39)"} .
```